# nginx: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/scv+xml: "http://localhost/landloss/HTML5-logo.svg".

Tags: html, svg, nginx

I am trying to serve a SVG file on NGINX. My conf file looks like this, including a types declaration for SVG:

```
pid logs/nginx.pid;
error_log logs/nginx_error.log;

events {     
    worker_connections  1024; 
}

http {
    server {
        root /data/www;
        types {
            text/html  html;
            image/gif  gif;
            image/jpeg jpg;
            image/scv+xml svg;
        }

        location /static{
        }
    }

}
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<img src="logo.svg"></img>
```

If I open a browser, I see this in developer tools

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/scv+xml: "http://localhost/workingdir/HTML5-logo.svg".
```

How can I get this hosted as SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct mime type for svg is image/svg+xml I'm not sure where you've got scv from.